# normalization of 2D FFT

Tags: python, fft, normalization

I have a simple question regarding normalization when doing a 2D FFT in python.
My understanding is that normalization factors can be determined from making arrays filled with ones.

For example in 1d, FFT of [1,1,1,1] would give me [4+0j,0+0j,0+0j,0+0j] so the normalization factor should be 1/N=1/4.

In 2D, FFT of [[1,1],[1,1]] would give me [[4+0j,0+0j],[0+0j,0+0j]] so the normalization should be 1/MN=1/(2*2)=1/4.

Now suppose we have a 3000 by 3000 matrix, each element with a Gaussian distributed value with mean 0. When we FFT and normalize this (normalization factor = 1/(3000*3000)), we get a mean power of order 10^-7.

Now we repeat this using a 1000 by 1000 element sub-region (normalization factor = 1/(1000*1000)). The mean power we get from this is of order 10^-6.  I'm wondering why there is a factor of ~10 difference. Shouldn't the mean power be the same? Am I missing an extra normalization factor?

If we say that the factor difference is infact 9, then I could guess that this comes from the number of elements (3000 x 3000 has 9 times more elements than 1000 x 1000), but what is the intuitive reason for this extra factor? Also, how do we determine the absolute normalization factor to obtain the "true" underlying mean power?

Any insight will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

sample code:

```
import numpy as np
a   = np.random.randn(3000,3000)
af  = np.fft.fft2(a)/3000.0/3000.0
aP  = np.mean(np.abs(af)**2)

b   = a[1000:2000,1000:2000]
bf  = np.fft.fft2(b)/1000.0/1000.0
bP  = np.mean(np.abs(bf)**2)

print aP,bP

>1.11094908545e-07 1.00226264535e-06
```

Comment: I think the FFT is also an averaging process, so you need to compensate based on the quantization. 20.log(3,10) = 9.54 : your factor is maybe here. More : http://www.lumerink.com/courses/ece697/docs/Papers/The%20Fundamentals%20of%20FFT-Based%20Signal%20Analysis%20and%20Measurements.pdf

Answer (score 3):

First, it's important to note that this issue is not related to the difference between 1D and 2D FFTs, but rather to how total power and mean power scale with the number of elements in an array.

You are exactly right when you say that the factor of 9 comes from the 9x more elements in `a` than `b`. What is confusing, perhaps, is that you noticed that you've already normalized by dividing by `np.fft.fft2(a)/3000./3000.` and `np.fft.fft2(b)/1000./1000.` In fact, those normalizations are necessary to get the total (not mean) power to be equal in the space and frequency domains. To get the mean you have to divide again by the array sizes.

Your question is really about Parseval's theorem, which states that the total power in the two domains (space/time and frequency) are equal. Its statement, for DFT is [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/b/e/8/be83fa81d5079316074327a33c367ba1.png). Notice, that in spite of the 1/N on the right, this is not *mean* power, but *total* power. The reason for the 1/N is the normalization convention for the DFT.

Put in Python, this means that for a time/space signal `sig`, Parseval equivalence may be stated as:

`np.sum(np.abs(sig)**2) == np.sum(np.abs(np.fft.fft(sig))**2)/sig.size`

Below is a complete example, starting with some toy cases (one and two dimensional arrays filled one 1s) and ending with your own case. Note that I used the `.size` property of numpy.ndarray, which returns the total number of elements in the array. It's equivalent to your `/1000./1000.` etc. Hope this helps!

```
import numpy as np

print 'simple examples:'

# 1-d, 4 elements:
ones_1d = np.array([1.,1.,1.,1.])
ones_1d_f = np.fft.fft(ones_1d)

# compute total power in space and frequency domains:
space_power_1d = np.sum(np.abs(ones_1d)**2)
freq_power_1d = np.sum(np.abs(ones_1d_f)**2)/ones_1d.size
print 'space_power_1d = %f'%space_power_1d
print 'freq_power_1d = %f'%freq_power_1d

# 2-d, 4 elements:
ones_2d = np.array([[1.,1.],[1.,1.]])
ones_2d_f = np.fft.fft2(ones_2d)

# compute and print total power in space and frequency domains:
space_power_2d = np.sum(np.abs(ones_2d)**2)
freq_power_2d = np.sum(np.abs(ones_2d_f)**2)/ones_2d.size
print 'space_power_2d = %f'%space_power_2d
print 'freq_power_2d = %f'%freq_power_2d

# 2-d, 9 elements:
ones_2d_big = np.array([[1.,1.,1.],[1.,1.,1.],[1.,1.,1.]])
ones_2d_big_f = np.fft.fft2(ones_2d_big)

# compute and print total power in space and frequency domains:
space_power_2d_big = np.sum(np.abs(ones_2d_big)**2)
freq_power_2d_big = np.sum(np.abs(ones_2d_big_f)**2)/ones_2d_big.size
print 'space_power_2d_big = %f'%space_power_2d_big
print 'freq_power_2d_big = %f'%freq_power_2d_big
print


# asker's example array a and fft af:
print 'askers examples:'
a = np.random.randn(3000,3000)
af = np.fft.fft2(a)

# compute the space and frequency total powers:
space_power_a = np.sum(np.abs(a)**2)
freq_power_a = np.sum(np.abs(af)**2)/af.size

# mean power is the total power divided by the array size:
freq_power_a_mean = freq_power_a/af.size

print 'space_power_a = %f'%space_power_a
print 'freq_power_a = %f'%freq_power_a
print 'freq_power_a_mean = %f'%freq_power_a_mean
print
# the central 1000x1000 section of the 3000x3000 original array:
b = a[1000:2000,1000:2000]
bf = np.fft.fft2(b)

# we expect the total power in the space and frequency domains 
# to be about 1/9 of the total power in the space frequency domains 
# for matrix a:
space_power_b = np.sum(np.abs(b)**2)
freq_power_b = np.sum(np.abs(bf)**2)/bf.size
# we expect the mean power to be the same as the mean power from
# matrix a:
freq_power_b_mean = freq_power_b/bf.size

print 'space_power_b = %f'%space_power_b
print 'freq_power_b = %f'%freq_power_b
print 'freq_power_b_mean = %f'%freq_power_b_mean
```